# spring migration 4 to 5; what is causing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am migrating an old app from Spring 4 to 5. It builds fine with Maven, but when I start the app in jboss 7.1, I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Spring 5.3.20
Hibernate 5.3.28.Final

I have been following this guide, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x

This said Hibernate 5 is required, so I updated that in the pom to 5.3.28.Final

Here is relevant snippet of spring-context.xml:

```xml
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.bean.FooService</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Running with Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

The relevant parts of the migration guide are:

> Hibernate support has been upgraded to a Hibernate ORM 5.2+ baseline, with a focus on ORM 5.4.x.

This indicates that the minimum version of Hibernate is now Hibernate 5.2.

and

> Packages `web.view.tiles2` and `orm.hibernate3/hibernate4` dropped.

This indicates that the package your XML config is using (`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4`) no longer exists. Searching for `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in the [Spring Framework 5.3.22 apidoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.22/javadoc-api/) shows [`org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.22/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html). Its API seems compatible with your XML definition, so changing the `class` property should be all that you need to change.

Comment: Thanks yea that was it; I saw that and started heading down that path, looking for some doc to verify that might be it; actually felt a bit foolish for not trying that first